# I can't find a way to delete rows with strings in my csv file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

As a begginer to python and coding all together, and I have been trying for a while to make a script to clean up a CSV file I have for training.

Thanks to df.dropna I have succesfully taken out all the blank spaces, but I have from time to time parts of wrong 'text' imputs in my CSV that I just can't find the way to fix ! take this sample of row from my file as an example :

0,0.0,0.0,0.0,zero,0.0,0.0

I want for my script to be able to scan my CSV file, find those String errors, and erase the whole row they are in.

I kinda made up this code in an effort to go row by row of each column and search for my errors and erase them, but nothing I do works :

```
Totalrows = len(df.index)
TotalColumns = df.shape[1]
CurrentColumn = 0


while CurrentColumn < TotalColumns:
    CurrentRow = 1
    while CurrentRow < Totalrows:
        if df.loc[CurrentRow, CurrentColumn] == str:
            df.drop(CurrentRow, axis=0, inplace=True)
    CurrentRow + 1
CurrentColumn + 1
```

The solution i find most of the time is "df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])" but that doesn't work for me as my cells don't have a date value in them. so what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think i managed to do it using a simple try catch block.
I loop over the dataframe rows and convert each one of them to a float array. If the try-catch detects an exception than it deletes the row from the df.
At the end i wrote the resulting df in a .csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/aless/Desktop/test.csv') #your initial csv file
print(df.values)
for id,row in enumerate(df.values):
    try:
        y = row.astype(np.float64)
        print("Row "+str(id)+" is OK")
    except:
        df=df.drop(axis=0,index=id)

print(df.values)
df.to_csv('C:/Users/aless/Desktop/testRepaired.csv',index=False) #file path to write results
```

Initial Csv

[image: Initial Csv (before processing)]

Final Csv

[image: Final Csv (after processing)]